# Import string data into ControlLogix PLCs via VBA DDEPoke

Tags: excel, vba, plc

I'm working on a utility to update certain functional tag values in a ControlLogix processor. The tags are controller scope and I currently have the program running on an emulator locally. The goal is to transfer certain information from one column of the Excel table to a tag named in an adjacent column for two pieces of information, one a DINT and one a STRING.

My VBA code triggers successfully off of a button click:

```
Sub CreateTags()
Dim rslinx As Long
Dim messageid As String
Dim Message As String
Dim severityid As String
Dim severity As Long
Dim channel As String

rslinx = DDEInitiate("RSLinx", "TestAE2")

channel = CStr(rslinx)

'Check if the connection was made
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error Connecting to topic" + channel, vbExclamation, "Error"
    rslinx = 0 'return false value for bad conn
End If

If Err.Number = 0 Then
    MsgBox "RSLinx Connection Established. Channel is " + channel, vbDialog, "Success!"

End If

For i = 0 To 550
    On Error Resume Next

    messageid = Sheet3.Cells(6 + i, 7)
    severityid = Sheet3.Cells(6 + i, 8)
    Message = Sheet3.Cells(6 + i, 3)
    severity = Sheet3.Cells(6 + i, 2)

    Sheet3.Cells(2, 1) = severity
    Sheet3.Cells(2, 2) = Message

    DDEPoke rslinx, messageid, Message
    DDEPoke rslinx, severityid, severity

Next i     

End Sub
```

This program runs without any issues and the dialog box to note the successful connection appears and displays the channel properly.

I'm wondering if this might be a matter of incompatible datatypes (Hence the use of the type declarations at the top.)

I'm new to both VBA and ControlLogix processors.

Comment: In `DDEPoke` I think you need to specify a range as the Data, eg `DDEPoke rslinx, messageid, Sheet3.Cells(2, 2)`.  You are also not terminating your connection at the end of your code (`Application.DDETerminate rslinx`)

Comment: Hmm.. so I guess it could be necessary to have a range defined for each subsection of a given tag?

I'm thinking specifically of the string where there is an array in RSLogix for each individual character in ASCII. 

Thanks for your thoughts chris.